# Show that if exist $\mu$, $k$ such that $\lVert e^{At} x\rVert\leq ke^{-\mu t}\lVert x\rVert$, then $x'=Ax'$ is topologycal conjugated to $x'=-x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that if exist $\mu>0$, $k\geq 1$ such that $\lVert e^{At} x\rVert\leq ke^{-\mu t}\lVert x\rVert$, for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (condition 1), then $x'=Ax'$ is topologycal conjugated to $x'=-x$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (condition 2).

This a proposition about equivalence, if $x'=Ax$ is an "atractor" (condition 0) then implies condition 1 and 2. I proved that $\mbox{ condition 0}\implies\mbox{ condition 1}$ and  $\mbox{ condition 2}\implies\mbox{ condition 0}$, but I can not see $1)\implies 2)$, any hint. Thanks!

Comment: This is indeed tricky in case you really want to exhibit a conjugacy. Anyways, I suggest defining a new norm by $\|x\|'=\int_0^\infty \|e^{At}x\|\,dt$ and looking at the set defined by $\|x\|'=1$. Still far from constructing the conjugacy but this is the main idea.

Comment: Ok, I also thought this is tricky, thanks for the answer!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Palis' and de Melo's _Geometric theory of dynamical systems: An Introduction_ has a proof for this statement.